# Copiar contenido de un grupo de celdas las veces que el usuario desea con macros VBA en excel

Tags: excel, vba, visual, basic

buen dia a todos, en este momento he estado trabajando en un proyecto el cual va de la siguiente manera (adjunto Imagen)
he estado trabajando con macros y VBA pero necesito copiar esa hoja de informacion, pero que el usuario elija cuantas veces lo quiere copiar, para ello he elejido que el usuario diga desde que numero de tarima desea empezar y donde terminar, Ejemplo: si el usuario quiere imprimir desde la tarima 10 a la 20 en total se copiarian 10 papeletas y su numero de tarima empezaria de 10,11.....20 lo que quiero es que al apretar el boton auntomaticamente se copien este formato haciendo espacio para una hoja y si son mas ocupar otra y asi sucesivamente, de hecho este grupo de celdas le he nombrado como "PapeletaIni"
las celdas que recibiran texto se llaman "valorIni" y "ValorFin" y al boton de replicar le puse el mismo nombre de variable, espero puedan ayudarme por favor, ya he avanzado un poco pero me pierdo mucho ahi, muchas gracias [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no pongas nunca el código como imagen.

Comment: @Elier Sánchez E-Infantes Hola, disculpa me puedes explicar porque razón no puedo poner código como imagen? en realidad llevo poco tiempo en este foro, gracias

Comment: Si pones código como imagen, no podemos copiarlo para reproducirlo, tendríamos que estar escribiendo a mano todo, en vez de copiar y pegar. Por favor, lee bien [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Elier Sánchez E-Infantes muy cierto, no lo había notado, gracias por la aclaración lo tomare en cuenta en mis siguientes preguntas en el foro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿ El objetivo es generar copias del formato para luego imprimirlos...?

Si es así, seria mas simple generar un procedimiento que vaya cambiando el numero de tarima y luego imprimirla, incluso puedes generar pdf justo después de poner el nuevo numero.

Algo como esto puede servir.

```
Sub Imprime()
    Dim ini As Integer, fin As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    
    ini = Range("ValorIni").Value
    fin = Range("ValorFin").Value
    
    For i = ini To fin
        Range("nTarima").Value = i
        ActiveSheet.PrintOut
    Next i
End Sub
```